# How do I programmatically register a service with the AD server?

Tags: active-directory

I have a new service that I have written and need to register it with the client's AD server.  Is there a tutorial on how to do this?  (Google has not been kind to me yet.)
I am talking about Microsoft's Active Directory server.  Is an openLDAP server different?

Comment: It might help if you name the ad server your trying to work with.

Comment: It would also help if you explained what kind of service you were hoping to register...

Comment: I don't think that the type of service matters.  I am interested in running a service of name SERVICE on a HOST in a DOMAIN.  Does it really matter what the name of the service is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Registering a service" is not a core AD verb...so it's not super clear what you are trying to do based upon the question above.
With more data about what you are trying to do with this registration we could better help.

Typically when people ask this they mean one of two things:
0) Register a service principal name (aka SPN) for Kerb mutual auth purposes.
1) Register their service in the directory so that clients can discover the presence of this service on the network and find their way to a service endpoint. For this they typically use DNS, SCPs (an object type in the AD schema natively, which you can create if you so choose for your own purposes) or a custom object type of some sort (ex: Exchange).

If you mean something else holler...

Comment: Eric, thanks for the answer.  I meant the registration to be of the second type you mention (so that clients can discover the service endpoint).  I will study up on SCPs.

Comment: SCPs are very simple and there is no in-box support for discovering based upon the existence of them. However, if you're writing code anyway, you can use them or another object type of your choosing (ie extend the schema). SCPs are only nice in that they are in the schema already.